# Modifying some property of a document using Spring data mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, jersey, spring-data-mongodb

I was wondering that I am trying to update **one** or **two** property of a **document** of **collection** `user` having some property such as

```
{
  "id": "591fcd33f8bb03598ec34f70",
  "name": null,
  "username": "abc",
  "emailId": "abc@gmail.com",
  "interestedFlag": 1,
  "mobNo": "xxxxxxxxxx",
  "userActiveFlag": 1,
  "address": "1",
  "city": "abx",
  "state": "up",
  "profileImage": [
    {}
  ],
  "joinedOn": null,
  "modifiedOn": null,
  "lastVisited": null,
  "tempPassword": "1234567",
  "sex": null,
  "metaDataMap": {},
  "dob": null
}
```

Suppose I wanted to update `user` **name** only and if I am running `save` with the following command :

```
userRepository.save(userEntity);
```

It changed my user as :

```
{
  "id": "591fcd33f8bb03598ec34f70",
  "name": "New Name",
  "username": null,
  "emailId": null,
  "interestedFlag": null,
  "mobNo": null,
  "userActiveFlag": null,
  "address": null,
  "city": null,
  "state": null,
  "profileImage": null,
  "joinedOn": null,
  "modifiedOn": null,
  "lastVisited": null,
  "tempPassword": null,
  "sex": null,
  "metaDataMap": {},
  "dob": null
}
```

But Ideally I want to change my ***user's name*** only .

My **user controller** is :

```
@PATCH
@Path("/changepassword/{userId}")
@Consumes("application/json")
public User changeName(@PathParam("userId") String userId, final User user) {
    userService.changePassword(user);
    return user;
}
```

My **serviceImpl** is :

```
@Override
public User changeName(User user){
    User userEntity = userRepository.findById(user.getId());
    userEntity.setName(user.getName());
    return userRepository.save(userEntity);
}
```

My **mongoRepository** is :

```
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String>
```

Please help me out to achieve this in a correct way with **Spring-data-mongodb** .

Comment: This will help. http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb-template-update

Comment: you have to use MongoTemplate for that

Answer (score 1):

As guys wrote in comments you should create an custom update method for that.

First create an interface for custom methods:

```
interface UserRepositoryCustom {
   void updateName(String userId, String newName);
}
```

Then add it to `UserRepository`:

```
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String>, UserRepositoryCustom
```

And implementation for it:

```
public class UserRepositoryImpl implements UserRepositoryCustom {

    private final MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    public UserRepositoryImpl(@Autowired final MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
        this.mongoTemplate = mongoTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateName(final String id, final String newName) {
        mongoTemplate
                .updateFirst(Query.query(Criteria.where(Entity.Meta.ID).is(id)),
                        Update.update("name", newName), User.class);
    }
}
```

Also you should always update only fields that you want to update.
`Save` method should be use rarely.